# Displaying a graph with minimum overlapping edges

Tags: graph-theory, sorting, clustering

### Context

I am developing UI for a skill web for a mobile game. Each skill may have requirements from other skills, or sometimes no requirement at all.

---

### The problem

The description above is perfectly captured in a directed graph. I want to display this graph as aesthetically pleasing as possible, along with functionality and interactivity.

---

### Guidelines

Obviously that is the vaguest question ever. But after I sat down to analyse what I actually meant by "aesthetically pleasing", as well as what interactivity I want from the final result, I came up with concrete guidelines:

1. Minimise longest edge between any two nodes. Of course this will be a value after normalisation.
2. Avoid edges crossing each other where possible.
3. Basic interactions: rotation, scaling, and moving the graph. Keep in mind that these don't actually concern the final algorithm, but they are good to keep in mind.

---

### Approaches

So with those guidelines in mind, I thought about how to render this graph. I came up with two approaches:

1. Put nodes on the graph one at a time, and use the greedy approach to make sure each new node is in the best position available.
2. Dump all nodes randomly (for example, in a grid) first, then try iterate through all the nodes by moving connected nodes closer together and thus try to reduce the maximum normalised edge length in the graph.

As for preventing edges from crossing, I thought about grouping nodes in clusters/communities based on the number of connecting edges with other nodes in the same group, but I'm not exactly sure how that would incorporate in the solution.

---

### Drawbacks

Both methods have drawbacks. Method 1 can never move other vertices during the process, and may result in lack of space. Imagine we are drawing a rectangle-shaped graph. The algorithm only sees single nodes so it doesn't know we are trying to draw a rectangle. We might end up with a shape that looks like:
[image]

And obviously the square would be the one minimising all the edge lengths (after normalisation, if you will).

Method 2, on the other hand, does not actually rotate stuff, so if we are trying to draw a triangle-shaped graph that looks like:

[image]

after initial random layout, and we try to move vertices together, that will just give the same layout on a smaller scale.

---

### The question

I need to get a hold on a good sorting/clustering algorithm, or at least a good idea/approach, that can display a list of nodes in a directed graph on a plane such that the above guidelines are met.

Comment: It seems strange that there would be directed cycles in a graph where one, presumably (correct me if i'm wrong), progresses through skills.  In the example of a directed $C_3$ given above, how would this relate to skills in the game?  For example, i think this would correspond to something like: firebolt $\to$ fireblast $\to$ firestorm $\to$ firebolt.  Which doese't make sense to me as the most advanced skill predicates the most basic skill.  Am I correct in assuming that we should end up with a digraph with no directed cycles?

Comment: Indeed, perhaps the final product there will not be any directed cycles, but I want to have a general example. My current approach is to use a physics approach (since I'm using a game engine that comes with a physics engine), but that doesn't seem to work well in all scenarios, and I would very much like to see if there are other viable approaches to the problem.

Comment: To draw graph I usually use Graphviz. You may want to use it as well to your graph I guess you can tune the options to fit your requirements. Otherwise take a look at http://graphviz.org/Documentation.php the paper section gives you most of the algorithm used that you may want to tune for your case.